# Best practices for breaking up functional blocks?

Tags: programming, function-construction, scoping

Say I have a main function that does some job, and I'm only interested in the final result of `ans`, i.e., the local functions are not important and produce no side-effects:

```
mymain[...]:=Block[{ans,func1,func2,func3},
               func1[...]:=Block[];
               func2[...]:=Block[];
               func3[...]:=Block[];
               ans = func1[...] + func2[...] + func3[...]
             ];
```

Would it be better to leave the local functions in the block as in the code above, or to take them out of the main function?

I know this is not very specific. But I want to know some general guidance, of how to write "large" functions. Would there be any advantage of memory usage or efficiency of the program?

Comment: If the inner functions are broken out, it's easier to test them for correctness initially and in case of any later changes. In a notebook, comments and examples can more easily be given for the subsidiary functions if they're located in their own cells rather than inserted into a larger function. Apart from that, I think it's mostly a question of style, so it depends largely on whether this code is written by you for your own use only or written for/by others as well, and what structure and conventions will be most convenient as a result. There won't be any big effect on efficiency.

Comment: Also, be careful when using `Block` as your primary scoping construct. I use it a lot myself, but it requires a certain amount of care. Normally, `Module` would be recommended, as it avoids the problems of `Block`.

Comment: @OleksandrR. Thanks. Yes, I read a lot about `Module` and `Block`. I read that most of the time they are "equivalent" and `Block` are "faster" in general. So far, I have not yet had major problems. The functions are solely written by myself and I always test them before I put them into the main function.

Comment: @OleksandrR. please consider writing a short summary of your comments in form of an answer. :)